# NU1608 Detected package version outside of dependency constraint

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I'm getting this warning on a Service Fabric project:

```
NU1608: Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Microsoft.ServiceFabric.AspNetCore.Abstractions 6.1.1390 requires Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services (= 6.1.1390) but version Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services 7.0.1001 was resolved.
```

The csproj file has no reference to Microsoft.ServiceFabric.AspNetCore.Abstractions, so I guess my first question is, how can I figure out what package depends on it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services version 7.0.1001 - my guess is that you're using Azure DevOps and it's picking up on and caching unlisted packages from NuGet. I just filed a [bug report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/When-DevOps-repository-added-to-NuGet-in/10388800) with Azure DevOps.

You'll note that version 6.1.1799 is the latest version [available on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services/). Downgrade to this version and I expect your issue will magically resolve as it'll no longer experience an expected version mismatch.